# why is Ubuntu blocking pluggin download from Avogadro 1.93.0 software?

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu

After installing Avogadro on Ubuntu, I opened it and tried to download the plugins under the extensions option.
However, it was stopped.
Avogadro apk crached.
I tried several times and this was the case every time

Comment: What release of lubuntu?  From the package version I'd assume you mean *focal* (1.93.0-1 is the package available for *focal*) but it's best if we're told. Do you get any messages? are there any in logs?  Currently we have nothing to understand your issue, and don't even know your release of Lubuntu.

Comment: If you tell us what you are running we can direct you to a *.deb file that will install for your version.